# Which is the more accepted spelling between “doughnut” or “donut” in formal academic prose?

Tags: terminology, orthography, slang, formality, trademarks

From what I understand, the term *donut* arose as a shortening for the word *doughnut*. The former has become much more common, though.

Which word is more accepted in academia: the more formal but somewhat less common (*doughnut*), or more common (at least casually) but less formal (*donut*)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50215/discussion-on-question-by-brendan-b-which-is-the-more-accepted-spelling-between).

Comment: Well it is made of dough not "do" so I'm pretty sure people in academia would lean towards doughnut. I would guess the a torus is normally described as doughnut-shaped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When asking about contemporary usage *in academia* it is almost always better to simply check usage in the specific domain. For example, in mathematics and engineering the word "doughnut" / "donut" may be used to refer to a [torus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus).

"Doughnut" currently seems preferred in both the humanities and sciences -- although both are used -- based on the following quick inspections.

For the humanities, JSTOR ("a digital library of academic journals, books, and primary sources") lists:

- '[doughnut](http://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=doughnut)' 4699 / '[donut](http://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=donut)' 2314

Google Scholar returns more results and with higher citation counts for '[doughnut](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=doughnut)'. Top results are almost all metaphorical uses in the sciences, like the "banana-doughnut paradox" in geophysics. There are fewer listings for '[donut](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=donut)', and the highest cited is actually an article with JR Donut as a named author, not even a usage as a common noun! (Ironically, even this was an OCR error while scanning the name of [JR Donat](http://wrjdeoa.aslo.net/lo/toc/vol_36/issue_8/1555.pdf)).

Note that searching JSTOR and Google Scholar with a recent time-window may indicate a narrowing of the gap in recent years. While even recent top-cited articles predominantly use 'doughnut', the total proportion of 'donut' titles has grown in the past decade. However different groups of academics are often writing for very specific audiences. If you are citing previous research that uses a particular spelling then you should probably follow that usage. The editors of a specific journal may also have opinions based on their chosen style guides or references, e.g. AP Style prefers "doughnut." Your field or publisher may vary!

Comment: Yes, good answer!!!

Comment: JOSH - Your answer was excellent as well; I'm sorry you deleted it. But thank you for supporting JeremyDouglass' answer; you're a true gentleman!

Comment: Consider  the British and American English divide though.... How many of those  donuts were American? I bet each and every single one of them was :)

Comment: @JOSH - Thank you! Consider restoring some version of your very useful answer with style guide and usage examples, as mine does not contain that material.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Not entirely :) Academic jargon tends toward globalization. One example: The Dutch publisher Elsevier puts out the international Journal of Theoretical Biology, which published [an article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519309000708) with two authors from the Chinese Academy of Sciences, Beijing on "Donut-shaped fingerprint in homologous polypeptide relationships."

Comment: Surely that's more to do with the translation of the Chinese article into English, and the translator that chose to used the 'donut-shaped' spelling at the time?

Comment: @Grim - this particular example isn't a translation, it is an original publication in English. Even if it was originally drafted in Chinese before the authors published it, that wouldn't make their choice of usage an "American donut" -- any more than it would make it a "Dutch donut" or an "international donut." They are the authors -- it is their donut.

Comment: *"(Ironically, even this was an OCR error while scanning the name of JR Donat)."* I would be so mad if I were that guy.

Comment: I thought this discussion was about 'donut' vs. 'doughnut' - not the global origin of said doughnut!  My point was, the Chinese spelling is obviously in Chinese/Mandarin letters/symbols and at some point was changed to 'the Western version'.

Comment: But note that if you restrict publications in Google Scholar to the most recent ten years, *donut* begins to outstrip *doughnut*. The longer spelling still wins in JSTOR, but the gap narrows considerably.

Comment: @Grim: The discussion so far in brief: Mari-LouA: I bet every "donut" was  American. Jeremy: Not all of them are American usage. Grim: But that's example is translated. Jeremy: No, that is an original English publication, and still not American. Grim: But we aren't talking about origin, and it is translated. Jeremy: ...? No, we *are* talking about the origins of usage. This usage is an English publication originating from Beijing University. Unless you are claiming that no Chinese academics can read or write English, but you can't be saying that.

Comment: @1006a -- I like your passionate 'donut' advocacy! Who knows, maybe it is trending towards catching up. That's why my answer is "check your specific domain." I don't actually see evidence in top articles that it is preferred in recent years, however, as academic discourse is citations as much as / more than raw title counts. The top 'doughnut' articles  are cited x325(2006), x273(2012), x100(2012), while the top 'donut' articles are cited x103(2007), x85(2008), x70(2013). Donut might be trending up, but doesn't look more popular _or_ more recent. Your sub-field may vary!

Comment: Heh, I'm not a passionate advocate for either spelling (though I am, in fact, passionately in favor of the confection itself, regardless of spelling—I'm partial to pączki in February), just thought I'd point out that there may be a trend towards less formality. It wouldn't entirely surprise me if the shorter spelling prevails in another several decades, even among British academics.

Comment: \*shrug\* The usage data you give says to me that "doughnut" and "donut" are both perfectly acceptable and you should use whichever you prefer. The journal's copy-editor may also have an opinion.

Comment: @JeremyDouglass - you're right, I wasn't saying that!  This has gone beyond my knowledge level of academia now; I'm an engineer, not a professor, so I'll leave it at that.